# Indexeddb seems to not free memory

Tags: memory-leaks, indexeddb, localforage

I'm using [localforage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) with its IndexedDB driver for storing simple key-value-pairs. But I encountered a problem when trying to remove or update values.

Whenever I call `localforage.removeItem("existingKey")` or `localforage.setItem("existingKey", "some value")` with a key of an existing entry no memory is freed.

When using WebSQL instead of IndexedDB the behavior does no occur.

[Example on JsBin](https://jsbin.com/gopamox/5/edit?js,console) (Only works in Chrome due to calls to `navigator.storage`)

Comment: Maybe Chrome keeps around deleted records in memory until memory needs to be freed, and/or the storage query algorithm incorrectly counts deleted records along with normal data? I know there is some complicated code around when data actually gets flushed to disk, so maybe the delete is not immediately flushed, and this behavior possibly varies by browser.

Comment: IndexedDB in Chrome will retain some memory while performing transactions until it reaches about 4Mb then it will dump.